# c# Datatable merge and add value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 2 datatable

TABLE1

```
 Type        Count

Orange         2
Apple          3
Pear           6
```

TABLE2

```
 Type        Count

Orange         3
Pear           2
Pineapple      1
Banana         4
```

I want to combine table 1 and table 2
and add both count. TABLE 3 as example

TABLE3

```
  Type        Count

    Orange         5
    Apple          3
    Pear           8
    Pineapple      1
    Banana         4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable` to group by type and sum the count:

```
var typeGroups = Table1.AsEnumerable()
    .Concat(Table2.AsEnumerable())              // all rows in one sequence
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Type")); // group all by type 
DataTable Table3 = Table1.Clone();              // empty, same columns
foreach (var typeGroup in typeGroups)
{
    DataRow newRow = Table3.Rows.Add();         // added already now
    newRow.SetField("Type", typeGroup.Key);
    newRow.SetField("Count", typeGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count")));
}
```

Comment: Sorry not very familiar with Linq-To-DataTable. if there arre more than 2 table to merge?

Comment: @Jonathan: then simply use multiple `Concats`: `t1.AsEnumerable().Concat(t2.AsEnumerable()).Concat(t3.AsEnumerable())...GroupBy(....)`.

Comment: I mean how can i loop it?

Comment: If you have a  `DataSet` or `IEnumerable<DataTable>` and you want to concat them in  a loop, you need to declare an `IEnumerable<DataRow> allRows`. Then it's straight-forward: `foreach(DataTable tbl in dataSet.Tables)allRows=allRows.Concat(tbl.AsEnumerable());`

Comment: @Jonathan: you don't even need the (explicit) loop. You can do it in one query: `var typeGroups = allTables.SelectMany(table => table.AsEnumerable()).GroupBy(r => ......)`